# can someone suggest a web spider?

Tags: web-crawler

Is there a web spider which can grap the contents of the forums?

My company does not provide the internet connection, so I want to grap the threads of a forum, then I can have a look at the contents in company.

I have tried the WebLech, it can just grap the static pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). I've used it to mirror whole (or part of) websites for offline use and it works fine. See [this article](http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/) for an introduction.

Comment: +1 I even use wget to mirror sites via FTP as a kind of backup